# Create a certain size file and filled with no data on iOS

Tags: iphone, filehandle

I'm developing an iphone app, I need to create a certain size file on filesystem and filled with NO data first, then seek to a offset and write data when get data from somewhere else
How can I do it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "file of certain size filled with no data". If the file has a length greater than zero, there are actual bytes (probably of value zero) in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [lseek BSD function](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/lseek.2.html) is explicitly capable of that.

`man lseek`:

> The lseek() function allows the file offset to be set beyond the end of the
>   existing end-of-file of the file. If data is later written at this point,
>   subsequent reads of the data in the gap return bytes of zeros (until data is
>   actually written into the gap).

Comment: This answer gives a simple code example using `lseek()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273353/1161906

Answer (score 1):

[NSMutableData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) or [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) is probably what you want