# Creating a large Dummy File

Tags: ios, file, nsdata

I'm new to this community and also new to iOS development, and I hope that someone can help me with a little problem...

Currently I'm writing a little app for myself, that should create a very large dummy file, with dummy data or words or whatever it makes it big.

The reason is, I would like to click a button and the app should generate a 4 gb file and save it to disk, that no other app could use it, because it isnt free... If I need the 4 gb of free space, I just have to open my little app, and after clicking another button, the file will be deleted, and i got 4 gb of free diskspace...

I know how to write files to disk but I have no idea how to generate a large amount of data in short time, to make it 4 or more gb big???

Does someone have an idea how to generate such a big file with a for loop or something?

Comment: What purpose would that large file have?  Why is it needed?

Comment: Can you please clarify what the file should contain?  Just random (printable) characters?  random binary data?  Nothing at all?

Comment: just to keep some space free... if the file is created other apps could not use it for themselves... if I need free space, I could delete the file to make some space free.... I need this for myself, to solve a problem with other apps... I know it wouldnt be interesting for someone else, but I realy could need it.. :-)

Comment: it could contain any data. random binary, random characters the main purpose is that the ios filesystem got 4 gb less free diskspace for other apps...

Comment: I can't think of a possible reason to need to block storage from other apps - you know that you can manage the amount of storage used by an app in Settings?

Comment: This would most likely NEVER get approved by Apple.  Good luck getting something like this in the App Store.

Comment: Hopefully it wouldn't get approved by Apple. We complain about Apple's restrictions but this is the sort of crap certain developers will do without those restrictions.

Comment: You have to handle errors in case you run out of room while creating this 4GB file anyway. So, if you accept that you are going to handle errors when creating a file, why not handle the errors when you actually need the space, rather than allocate space which the user might never need? Your user might run your app one time then never open it again.

Comment: ElJay there is no reason for Apple to approve something... Its just for myself... There will be no AppStore Release of it, because no one else cloud use it

Comment: Let's get back to the problem you're having. Why do you need to "reserve" disk space that other apps cannot use?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to occupy 4GB of disk space, then create a file, seek to 4GB and write a byte.  This will create a "sparse file" containing next-to-no data in next-to-no time!

This is C:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

int fd = open("/path/to/file", O_WRONLY, 0644);
if (fd >= 0)
{
    lseek(fd, 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, &fd, 1);
    close(fd);
}
```

**EDIT** Dropped `creat()` in favour of `open()` so the file mode can be specified.

Also error checking should be better than shown...

Comment: It might make more sense to create a few smaller files so that you can claim the space incrementally.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Will that make any difference?

Comment: This was just a suggestion for the OP. Your solution is fine. The idea is that if you want to claim just 1 GB, you will have to write another 3 GB dummy file to keep the space reserved. If you make four 1 GB files, you could claim the space incrementally without having to make more dummy files.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I agree; although the whole purpose of this is questionable anyway...

Comment: Another option is to use `truncate()`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20957844/1161906.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `NSMutableData` object and use `-setLength:` to expand it to 4GB. (`-setLength` will fill with zeros), before writing it out to a file.

I'm not sure how well iOS will cope with an `NSMutableData` object that large, however.

**Edit:** Example:

```
NSString *filename; // The location to save your file
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data setLength:4*1024*1024*1024];
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```

Bear in mind also that iOS will purge your app's data in certain directories if the device's available storage is low.

Comment: I don't know how iOS copes with large NSData objects - there should be no conceivable reason to do this.

Comment: Report back if this works on-device. I'd imagine your app will terminate with an out-of-memory error.

Comment: Just tried this and it turns out there is a maximum size for NSData, and it's less than 4GB

Comment: Hi,

I have tried it like this but it doesnt work for me... still 6 gb free disk space before and after the file creation ... :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can just write it in C, incrementally:

```
// a starting point:
const char path[] = "somewhere";
const size_t NBytesInBuffer = 1024;
/* fill buffer, if you like */
const char buffer[NBytesInBuffer] = {0};
FILE* const file = fopen(path, "w+");
assert(file);
const size_t ElementSize = sizeof(buffer[0]);

uint64_t nBytesWritten = 0;
while (UINT32_MAX > nBytesWritten) {
    nBytesWritten += ElementSize * fwrite(buffer, ElementSize, NBytesInBuffer, file);
}

fclose(file);
```

Memory consumption will not be an issue here. Of course, it will take some time to write the entire file, as it is I/O bound. You will probably want some real data in there one day, too :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

Open the command shell - cmd
Execute the following command in order to create a file of 1mb

```
fsutil file createnew ./test.tmp 1048576
```

Linux:

Use convert and copy command - dd

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.tmp bs=1M count=1
```

OS X & Solaris:

```
mkfile 1m test.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do rough calculation by 1000, not by 1024

```
 4 gb 
 4000 mb
 4000000 kb 
 4000000000 b 
32000000000 bits
```

And exactly it will be 34359738368 bits

And if you go on to write that much characters (a b c etc) to a text file, by loop, you will create a file of 4gb.

Comment: yes, but I was looking for a easier/better method/algorithm to get this done...I will try c.cams advice, if it doesnt work, I will do it your way...