# How can you create a large file in iOS quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to be able to create a large "dummy" file (around 1 GB) quickly. I am currently looping over a byte array and appending it to the file, but this results in may separate disk hits:

```
NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.path];
[handle seekToEndOfFile];

while (shouldContinue)
{
     NSData *dummyData = [self buildDummyData];
     [handle writeData:dummyData];
}
```

But this takes around 7 seconds to complete. I would like it to complete in less than 1 second. Is there a way to create a file and allocate its size without needing to append bytes to it?

Comment: You could always use fopen,fwrite,fclose.  That will save the writing data into memory then writing to file, then writing to memory again, then writing to file...  But writing 1GB/sec on a mobile device may be difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `truncate` to set the length of a file directly:

```
int success = truncate("/path/to/file", 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
if (success != 0) {
    int error = errno;
    /* handle errors here. See 'man truncate' */
}
```

Comment: Actually, on the simulator this works perfect. On an actual device this takes quite a while before I can write to the file.

Comment: If truncate() isn't doing the trick, there's likely no way to do it fast enough. The one remaining thing to try would be mmap().

Comment: While this still isn't as fast as I would like, it seems to be as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

[You can check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3967762/1671729).  It says that you can lseek() past the end of file (EOF) then write something.  The gap between the initial end of file and the bytes you wrote will return 0's if queried.

Comment: I am having trouble finding an example on how to use this. Can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in Objective-C, use `NSFileHandle` like you do in your example:

```
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:dummyFilePath];
if (file == nil) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:dummyFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:dummyFilePath];
}    
[file truncateFileAtOffset:sizeInMB * 1024 * 1024];
[file closeFile];
```

Note that this is *sloooow*. Writing a 1GB file takes over 30 seconds for me.

Another way to do it would be to do a write:

```
[file seekToFileOffset:sizeInMB * 1024 * 1024];
const unsigned char bytes[] = {1};
[file writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)]];
```

This was even slower for me, taking 55 seconds for the 1GB.