# How to create a big file just in seconds in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The question is related with 
[How can you create a large file in iOS quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957745/how-can-you-create-a-large-file-in-ios-quickly/20957844#20957844)
I want to prealloc a storage in iOS quickly and used the function truncate in iOS 10.2, and it works great, this API can create a 1GB file just in seconds. Then I do not need to worry about the storage will be used by other app.

But Apple released with iOS 10.3, and the new file system with APFS file system. This API did not return any error, but it seems iOS did not reserve the space for me, because after the API is called, I check the available space in my iPhone, it seems the storage space is still there, iOS did not create this file really.

So the question will be in iOS 10.3, is there any similar API I can used to reserve a big storage quickly.

```
int success = truncate("/path/to/file", 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
if (success != 0) {
    int error = errno;
    /* handle errors here. See 'man truncate' */
}
```

Comment: APFS is designed to prevent this.

Comment: Yes, I think I got the point of APFS, there should be no space are real alloced in this case、